# Empty all accounts in a smartcontract for a banking application

Tags: solidity, contract, banking, remix

I am working on a sample banking code in solidity. I wanted to use a so called "TakeAllTheMoney" and run function (just to give you an idea about the role of the function). 
This function should only be executable by the deployer of the contract and should give him the possibility to take all the money on the bank and transfer it to his account.

Problem: How can I empty also the account of the other user of the bank? Meaning that when a different user - not the deployer of the contract and of the function - uses the contract after the "TakeAllTheMoney" function is employed, he also sees 0 on his account.

Many thanks in advance

```
function TakeTheMoneyAndRun() public{
    require (msg.sender==Owner);
    balance[msg.sender] -= balance[msg.sender];
    (msg.sender).transfer( address(this).balance );
```

Expected results after employing this function:
Balance Bank = 0
Balance person that employed contract and function = 0 (since it went on his metamask account or similar)
Balance of every other user = 0

Again, thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You are mixing two things. User's amount in metamask and user sent amount to Bank in your case is Smart Contract and stored in some variable. So the amount you see in the metamask is the amount User own and has no link with the Smart Contract until and unless you send the money to the Smart Contract.

The Smart Contract in your case "Bank" the money sent by the user is store in the Smart Contract and the tracking of money recieve is stored in the array. Smart Contract itself does not holds the record of the previous transaction. So if you want to delete the Smart contract balance tracks of the User you have to empty that particular array. Although it sounds fishy if you want to implement it and wants to make the user accounts to zero in the Smart Contract.

Comment: Hi Uahmed, thanks for answering. Yes I know that, this are two distinct things but (obviously) I do not want to empty the Metamask accounts (which is impossible since it of the feature it has) but all the arrays. The idea is that all accounts, after deploying this function show 0. Any ideas how to do that? Thanks! :)

Comment: Yes I mean same about the Smart Contract data not about metaMask. As i said the Smart Contract it self does not hold the history of transactions so the total amount a user have in the Smart Contract(Bank) is store in some array. So in the Solidity code of Smart Contract you have to empty the value. In your case as per mention in the code i think you have to store all the address of the users in a seprate array and then send every address in a different function which takes the address but not the msg.sender as a value